# Aggregation: Mongodb aggregation query example

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Record is database:

```
[
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "author": [
      {
        "name": "user1",
        "register": true
      },
      {
        "name": "user2",
        "register": true
      }
    ],
    "tags": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "author": [
      {
        "name": "user1",
        "register": true
      },
      {
        "name": "user2",
        "register": true
      }
    ],
    "tags": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "title3",
    "author": [
      {
        "name": "user1",
        "register": true
      },
      {
        "name": "user2",
        "register": true
      }
    ],
    "tags": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"
    ]
  }
]
```

expected output:

```
{"tag":"tag1", "titles":["title1","title2","title3"], "size":3}
{"tag":"tag2", "titles":["title2","title4"], "size":2}
```

Can someone help with aggregate query?

Comment: can you update your question with what have you tried and update the question title to a meaningful title.

Comment: I'm trying to get output in this format using aggregate from a record which is I mentioned:
{"tag":"tag1", "titles":["title1","title2","title3"], "size":3}


I tried multiple title but It was not allowing me to post the question.

Comment: There is no "title4" in your sample input. Please provide valid sample data and result.

Comment: All `tags` have the same value. How do you expect different documents as result?

Answer (score 3):

You can use group

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$group` to regroup the based on tags
- `$project` to show the desired output

Here is the code,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$tags" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$tags",
      "titles": { "$push": "$title" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tag: "$_id",
      titles: 1,
      size: { $size: "$titles" },
      _id: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r1sCobPIzWb)**